# How to skip over C++ library constructors when single stepping in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, gdb

The following code was compiled with g++ using the flags -O0 -g3  (no optimization and request additional debug information respectively)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void foo(unordered_set<int> b)
{
    if (b.size()>0)
        cout<<*b.begin()<<endl;
}
int main(void)
{
    unordered_set<int> c={1};
    foo(c);
}
```

I am single stepping using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ , Oxygen.1a Release.
When I try to single step  into foo() the debugger begins displaying the many lines of the C++ Standard Library unordered_set copy constructor code.  If I step out of the copy constructor code this results in foo() also being stepped over.
I could set a breakpoint in foo, or run to a line in foo, but this is inconvenient.  Is there a simpler way to avoid single stepping thru the copy constructor code and directly into foo()?

Comment: Pass the set by reference, not by value. And do NOT do `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: Well, VS has a Step into Specific button. I don't know if Eclipse has an equivalent option.

Comment: When you step into a function on accident, all the debugger's I've used let you step out of the function. On gdb, the command is `finish`, but Eclipse may expose that functionality on some hotkey